# iOS Metal Swift newComputePipelineStateWithFunction not working error

Tags: ios, swift, gpu, metal

I've just started playing around with Metal in Swift to try and get some parallel computing going on the GPU, and I'm having some trouble specifically with the newComputePipelineStateWithFunction. I've looked at multiple sites like [Apple's Documentation for Data-Parallel Compute Processing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Compute-Ctx/Compute-Ctx.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH6-SW6) but I'm getting errors there too.

Here's the error I'm currently getting:

```
Incorrect argument label in call (have '_:error:', expected '_:completionHandler:')
```

I tried replacing the "error" with a completion handler but was having difficulty there too. Thanks in advance. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Metal

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var device: MTLDevice! = nil
    var defaultLibrary: MTLLibrary! = nil
    var thefunc: MTLFunction! = nil
    var pipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState!
    var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        setupMetal()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func setupMetal()
    {
        // Our default MTLDevice
        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        defaultLibrary = device.newDefaultLibrary()
        commandQueue = device.newCommandQueue()

        // Define the kernel function
        let kernelFunction: MTLFunction = defaultLibrary.newFunctionWithName("particleRendererShader")!

        // Define the pipeline state
        let pipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState = device.newComputePipelineStateWithFunction(kernelFunction, error: nil)

        // Define the command buffer
        let commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()

        // Define the command encoder
        let commandEncoder: MTLComputeCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.computeCommandEncoder()
        commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)



        // thefunc = library.newFunctionWithName("filter_main");
        // filterState = device.newComputePipelineStateWithFunction(thefunc, error: nil);
        // let kernelFunction = library.newFunctionWithName("filter_main")
        // pipelineState = device.newComputePipelineStateWithFunction(kernelFunction!, error: nil)



        // do {
        //     try pipelineState = device.newComputePipelineStateWithDescriptor(pipelineStateDescriptor)
        // } catch _ {
        //     print("Failed to create pipeline state, error")
        // }

    }

}
```

Comment: The Objective-C [`newComputePipelineStateWithFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLDevice_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLDevice/newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:error:) accepts an `error` argument, the Swift version doesn't. eg; `try pipelineState = device.newComputePipelineStateWithFunction(kernelFunction)` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I get the error "Errors thrown from here are not handled".

Comment: Yes, so instead of accepting an NSError as an input argument which you should check after calling the method, a more Swift way of doing things is to throw an exception. You'll need to wrap it in a `do {} catch {}`, much like what your commented out code does.

Comment: I think that worked, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
device.newComputePipelineStateWithFunction(function) { (state:MTLComputePipelineState?, error:NSError?) in

    }
```

Comment: This is one of the asynchronous variants of compute pipeline creation methods. To use it, you need to wait for the completion handler (written here as a trailing closure) to be called before encoding any compute work.